# Gmail recording with Jmeter

Tags: security, ssl, gmail, jmeter, recording

I would like to capture gmail with jmeter. so i am trying to record the script. but once i have started jmeter script and open the gmail in browser. i am getting below exception in browser.

can anyone provide solution for this please.

**This Connection is Untrusted
You have asked Firefox to connect securely to gmail.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.
Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.
What Should I Do?
If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.
This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate.
gmail.com uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown.
The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates.
An additional root certificate may need to be imported.
(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported the ssl certificate to firefox? it is located in the bin folder of your JMeter.

It is generated when you lanuch the https script recorder.

Comment: yes, i have imported root certificate from bin to mozilla. it is working fine now.Thankyou